# Accessing a library for .NET Framework from .NET 7/8 using Inter-Process-Communication

Tags: c#, .net, soap, ipc, rpc

I am working on an application where I need to use a vendor library for communication with external hardware. This library targets .NET Framework 3.5. A .NET standard 2.0 version of the library is planned but I don't think it will be coming any time soon. However I would like to develop my app in modern .NET versions like 7 or soon 8. Obviously I can't access a .NET Framework library from .NET 7/8 directly. So my idea was to create a separate .NET Framework process and communicate with it using some form of IPC. Both Assemblies would run on the same machine.

My first thought was to use gRPC but I am not sure if gRPC is available in .NET Framework as a server. The .NET Framework side of things would need to be called but also would need to call back when a message from the external Hardware was received. This is why I think I would need gRPC server capabilities in .NET Framework. Additionally with gRPC I would need to abstract the library to simple function calls.

My second idea was to provide wrappers for the .NET Framework library objects and let the .NET app access this wrapper using a stub. This would be like the SOAP protocol. But I never had to do anything like this in .NET. While looking for a solution a stumbled upon .NET Remoting and WCF. From what I understand WCF is superior to .NET Remoting so WCF might be the way to go. There is the CoreWCF implementation of WCF to allow .NET Core and newer .NET apps use WCF. However I heard that this should not be used in new projects.

The gist of my question is how do I use the .NET Framework library in .NET 7/8 in the most seamless way possible? Do I really need to resort to IPC or is there another way that I am missing? If IPC is indeed necessary what should I use in my situation? Any communication over something like named pipes would be interesting but if I would actually be able to wrap the library objects and make them available via stubs in the .NET 7/8 Process would be perfect.

Other than that what are my options to actually spawn the second process? I have found there was something called app domains but I think this is not possible in my situation. The normal CreateProcess API exists but I wonder if there is any better way given that the other process would essentially be a part of my application and only used by it.

I hope I am not asking the impossible here.

Comment: You also have the source code of the Net 3.5 assembly?

Comment: @Ralf No I don't.

Comment: Have you tried just referencing it? Unless the old library requires some obsolete features no longer present in .NET 7, you can typically just use it anyway. The format of .NET Framework assemblies is binary compatible to .NET 7.0.

Comment: Do you know the protocol that the lib is communicating to the HW in? If it's in "good ol' WCF" (or SOAP for that matter) you might be able to create your own client lib from a wsdl file? That's assuming their client lib doesn't do too much additional magic, of course.

Comment: The latest Net library have all the methods in one library.  Net 3.5 was incremental so you need to load Net 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5.  So for your code to run you need to install four Net Libraries.  Then what JonashH said should work.

Comment: @jdweng Only if used in its own process. If you load a .NET Framework lib (any version) into a .NET 6.0 process, no .NET Framework libraries are required.

Comment: @PMF : But the code will probably require modification if you upgrade to Net 6.0.  Using Net 3.5 the code will not need to be changed.

Comment: @PMF I was under the impression that the formats were inherently incompatible. It seems to work but I wonder if it fails when a feature that is obsolete is called by my program or is it enough that the feature is used somewhere in the DLL I am using. Because in my case I can instantiate a driver so obviously I can reference it. The question is can it break down the line when I use more features.

Comment: @patvax Since you don't have the source code you don't know what features it uses (I suppose), so all you can really do is try out. Any errors about incompatible functions will only be shown when they're actually used, so it might work now but no longer when you add more features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to just try to use it. Loading .Net framework libraries can work as long as they are not using any removed features. There are no guarantees however.

My guess is that your library is a fairly thin wrapper around a native library, so chances are good that it have no significant .net dependencies to worry about.

My next step would be to attempt gRPC. The main libraries target .net standard 2.0, so should work just fine in .net framework 4.6.1+. And .net framework 4.x can *probably* load your 3.5 library. I might also suggest trying MQTT, it is not really designed for point-to-point usage, but I found it fairly easy to get started, and will probably work well enough.

My understanding is that the classing .Net Remoting is no longer supported, so you probably want to avoid that. I think WCF was also removed in .net core, but there is a "CoreWCF" community project, so that could probably work.

But there are few maintained libraries with .net 3.5 support, so you will likely want to use .net framework 4.5+ regardless of the specific protocol and library you pick. And there is plenty of protocols and libraries to chose from.

Comment: The library is in fact a wrapper of a native library. It would seem I can reference the DLL and instantiate a driver so it seems to work. Let's say the library uses some obsolete feature not anymore existent in .NET 7. Would my test fail just because it is somewhere in the DLL or only if I actually call the code where that feature is used?

Comment: @patvax The code could fail at runtime if a method using the missing API is compiled, and methods are compiled the first time they are called. So in practice it should only fail if the feature is used. At least for the normal hitter, if you are using AOT compilation or similar I have no idea what would happen.